# Prolifics Panther in Angular environment

Tags: angular, rest

How best to reuse Prolifics Panther artifacts from existing applications in the new Angular-based 'ecosystem'? The platform is on-premises Redhat Openshift and Panther is version 5.52 (with REST functionality). Any experiences?

Answer (score 0):

Panther Web's REST support may be used simply for retaining legacy Panther functionality on the back-end with a non Panther Web front end.  In that respect, it should be fine for any type of client-side framework that supports REST (with JSON).
We have not tried it with Angular, but we have tried accessing  Panther resources with SoapUI, Dreamfactory, and Clientside JavaScript.